# sagemaker pytorch "Artifact upload failed"

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I'm running a test sagemaker pytorch training.
It creates the estimator runs the training successfully.
However it dies while runnning the "Uploading generated training model"

The error is "Error for Training job pytorch-training-2022-12-05-19-45-41-370: **Failed. Reason: ClientError: Artifact upload failed:Too many files are written**"

```
    estimator = PyTorch(  # create the estimator
        entry_point="CloudSeg.py",
        input_mode="FastFile",
        TrainingInputMode='FastFile',
        role=role,
        py_version="py38",
        framework_version="1.11.0",
        instance_count=1,
        instance_type="ml.g4dn.xlarge",
        checkpoint_s3_uri=checkpoint_s3_bucket,
        checkpoint_local_path=checkpoint_local_path,
        use_spot_instances=use_spot_instances,
        max_run=max_run,
        max_wait=max_wait,
        hyperparameters={"epochs": 1, "backend": "nccl"},
        )

    estimator.fit({"training": "s3://bucket/DATA/"})  # fit with the training data
```

The result of the fit is:

```
2022-12-05 19:54:10 Training - Training image download completed. Training in progress.
2022-12-05 19:54:10 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2022-12-05 19:54:10 Failed - Training job failed
ProfilerReport-1670269542: Stopping
-

UnexpectedStatusException                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_19821/1489485288.py in \<cell line: 1\>()
\----\> 1 estimator.fit({"training": 's3://picard-prov/38-cloud-simple-unet_DATA/'})
...
\~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait, poll, log_type)
3891
3892         if wait:
\-\> 3893             self.\_check_job_status(job_name, description, "TrainingJobStatus")
3894             if dot:
3895                 print()

\~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in \_check_job_status(self, job, desc, status_key_name)
3429                     actual_status=status,
3430                 )
\-\> 3431             raise exceptions.UnexpectedStatusException(
3432                 message=message,
3433                 allowed_statuses=\["Completed", "Stopped"\],

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job pytorch-training-2022-12-05-19-45-41-370: **Failed. Reason: ClientError: Artifact upload failed:Too many files are written**
```

## Any idea on how to solve this?

Thank you !

I tried getting rid of fastfile mode.  It didn't help

Comment: Can you add some code from your training script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed the problem.  I changed my "checkpoint_s3_bucket" to the session default bucket.  Haven't gotten an error since.

```
  bucket=sagemaker.Session().default_bucket()
  base_job_name="sagemaker-checkpoint-test"
  checkpoint_in_bucket="checkpoints"
  # The S3 URI to store the checkpoints
  checkpoint_s3_bucket="s3://{}/{}/{}".format(bucket, base_job_name, checkpoint_in_bucket)
```

Answer (score 0):

When training completes SageMaker will [process training outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-output.html), among things, it will upload the files that CloudSeg.py placed in /opt/ml/model. Check out how many files you end up placing in these output folders that SageMaker will upload to S3 in your behalf (According to the the error message it's too many).
`/opt/ml/model`
`/opt/ml/output`
You could write code to print out the files stored in there as the last step of your algorithm, or use something [SageMaker SSH Helper](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-ssh-helper) to interactively inspect what is happening.

Comment: I did print out my /opt/ml/model .  There is one .pt file there which I saved.  It is ~2G.  Still getting the error and don't know how to get past this problem.  I save the file with torch.save(model.state_dict(), '/opt/ml/model/outseg.pt')